# Sliding menu sliding to full screen android with sliding menu library

Tags: android, xml, slider

I am using  [Sliding menu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). When sliding the screen entire activity layout going to right side. But I want to fix the header at top and only need to go the remaining part.
My Sliding screen code is

```
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.sliding_screen);
    menu = getSlidingMenu();

    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    // menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
```

and I am included the header in layout

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/header_layout" />
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: You can try [navigation drawer](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2014/05/simple-navigation-drawer-example-in.html) instead of sliding menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT while attaching the menu to the activity.

Code:

```
SlidingMenu menu;
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.attachToActivity(activity, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this older, but if you are using the `SlidingFragmentActivity` (which means you aren't actually using `attachToActivity` as manishkumar suggested), then you should call `setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false)`. That will make it so that the Action Bar does not slide with the menu in a `SlidingFragmentActivity`